# How to create decorated rounded container sharing same divider line with colored border flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to replicate the list view below. It's a list view(or containers), that you can select, and it will make the border colored and apply a background with no padding between the containers, but there is a thing, they share the same divider line. I have already given a shot on this, but didn't quite work as I expected. Because the dividers lines got doubled (thicker), and it's kinda annoying.

**What I want:**

[image: List View that I am trying to make]

**EDIT:**

They are selectable containers, so you can click on each one and it will highlight the borders, so if you are thinking of making the middle container one with borders only at the right and left side, it will not work because you will not be able to highlight the top and bottom border.

**See the example below:**

[image: All the three containers can be selected, and they need to share the same divider line]

I was trying to make the first container with the bottom border transparent ( `bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.transparent),` ), so it would not get doubled. But it seems that you can not have a radius container in flutter with different border colors.

**What I have made:**

[image: List view that I have created]

```
Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.black)),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: use ``Border.only`` for the center container to add border.

Comment: But there is thing, each container is selectable, and the top and bottom container are rounded shape. So you will not be able to just paint the bottom or top border of it. I have some experience in flutter, but I am cracking my head to do this task

Comment: use a conditional statement to add borders

Comment: Even with conditional statement, I am still not able to have those three containers sharing the divider lines, it seems that if you have `BorderRadius` you must use `Border.all()` because you need the four sides of the square. I am trying to find a solution to make it possible

Answer (score 0):

For the middle `Container` use just `border:Border(left:,right:)`

```dart
   Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                left: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 1,
                ),
                right: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: But there is thing, each container is selectable. So how would you decorate all the four borders, to mark it as selected, if it has only two borders?

Comment: For selection can show border on two sides for middle containers and check index and set top container bottom border and bottom container's top border.

Comment: It seems that its not possible because the top and bottom container they are rounded ( radius container). And it you can not just paint the bottom ou top border of a rounded container. I have edited the post with a more detailed example. It’s was suppose to be a simple layout task, but it’s more complicated than it seems( at least for me). I have found some people with the same problem on Flutter’s github

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
            border: isTopSelected ? Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.red) : 
              Border(
                top: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1,
                ),
                left: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1,
                ),
                right: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: isMiddleSelected ? Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.red) :
                Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.Black),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
            border: isBottomSelected ? Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.red) : 
              Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1,
                ),
                left: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1,
                ),
                right: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't work, because your top container has a rounded border ( radius shape) and it also has borders, this error was given `A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border.
`. Flutter was not able to paint a simple shape like that, it was suppose to be a simple layout task. I am trying to find a simple way to do it.